# Fill the UltragridView with data

Tags: c#, windows

How can I fill an UltraGridView control?

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are asking for. And what is a `UltraGridView`?

Comment: ultraGridView is a infragistic control that can be used in windows forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ultraGridViewName.DataSource=yourDataTableName